# Where are the constants for the socket options documented?

Tags: ruby, sockets

*Crossposted, original post is in [Ruby Forum](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/6876877), but did not trigger any response so far*

Using the method `setsockopt`, I can set various options on a socket, for
example `Socket::SO_REUSEADDR`. I would like to know

- What constants are available (meaning, spelling),
- Which value they take, and
- What is the default value (for a given socket type)

I googled for a while, but aside from a few examples, I could not find
any documentation on this subject, even in the [official docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/). Does somebody know where I should look?

Comment: These are standard unix flags. For example: http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/4.5.shtml

Comment: Also `man getsockopt`

Comment: The `Socket` classes in Ruby are just a thin wrapper around the basic UNIX sockets available from the operating system. To find details about how these options affect sockets, refer to your OS's documentation. Note that these options are sometimes OS-dependent and might have different names or meanings or might even not exist on different OSs.

Answer (score 1):

Let's proceed step by step.

`Socket` comes from the [stdlib](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.0/libdoc/socket/rdoc/index.html).

With a rvm-managed installation, the file is located here:

```
$HOME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.3/lib/ruby/2.2.0/socket.rb
```

(this should help you locate it in different kind of installations too).

If you look at the source of the file, you'll see that it starts with `require 'socket.so'`. That means that the ruby library `socket` depends on the Unix [shared library](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13192/what-is-the-difference-between-a-and-so-file) `socket.so`.

The best way to get more info is via Unix man pages. In this case:

```
man setsockopt
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: While none of the responses posted did directly answered the question (the getsockopt/setsockopt man pages on my system (Cygwin) did not contain the description of the socket flags, and the socket FAQs only gave explanation of some of the flags, not a list of all of them), they all helped me figuring out the answer.

First, I found on the net this getsockopt [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/getsockopt), which is quite elaborate.

Further, since I learned from the answers, that socket.rb is just a layer on the native C, I conclude that what socket options are really available, depends on what compiler/library and which socket.h file was used, when Ruby was compiled.

While I don't know how Ruby is implemented on the Cygwin platform, it is not unreasonable to assume, that `/usr/include/asm/socket.h` was used, and this file indeed contains a list of the available options (and a terse description of their meaning).